# RPi A+ and Pi noIR: How to update just the camera driver NOT OS

Tags: raspbian, camera, update, rpi-update

I have a SD card, with Raspbian and lots of programs installed on it. I want to run it on model A+ and use the pi noIR camera module. The problem is that the OS firmware version is quite old. I know that by an OS firmware upgrade I can solve the camera issue, but I don't want to upgrade it due to some program compatibility issues.

Does anyone know which packages are related to the camera module so that I can just download and install them?

Thanks

Comment: It depends what you mean by the camera driver. The camera firmware is part of the Pi's firmware (you can't really update it separately), and the Pi's firmware is to some degree tied to the OS (especially with the recent device tree changes). It would probably help, if you post what camera issue you're actually trying to solve?